# Python storing Facebook ad sets in JSON and Creating Timer

Tags: python, json, facebook

I am new to Python and trying to write a script to control the budget for a campaign in Facebook's marketing API. You don't really need to know the Facebook Marketing platform to be able to help me because this is mostly a Python related question since I am new to Python and don't know how to go about writing this code.

```
#==========specify account ID in which the campaign you want to budget control resides=========================
AD_ACCOUNT_ID = 'act_4534633563'
#===============================================================================

campaign = Campaign(34635645764574)
fields = [
    AdSet.Field.name,
    AdSet.Field.lifetime_budget,
]
adsets = campaign.get_ad_sets(fields=fields)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    for adset in adsets:
        print(adset[AdSet.Field.name])
        json.dump(adset, f)
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\JSonTest1.py", line 50, in <module>
    json.dump(adset, f)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <AdSet> {
    "id": "534534533454353",
    "lifetime_budget": "50000",
    "name": "US, CA, BR, PL, CN, IN, PK, SA, DE, AR, VE, JP, EG - 14+ - Copy"
} is not JSON serializable
```

This script is supposed to allow campaign-level budget control by storing a given campaign's ad sets' id and Lifetime budget into JSON at the start of the day. Then this script is supposed to poll for the lifetime budget every six hours to subtract the current lifetime(the live data value) budget by the lifetime budget at the start of the day (which is stored every morning inside the JSON file). If the cumulative budget of all the ad set's lifetime reaches the user-specified campaign budget for the day, the campaign is paused for the day and then restarted the next day.

I have a couple of issues here.....

1. How do I overcome this JSON issue where it says the data I am trying to store is not serializable?
2. How can I store/read the JSON objects so that I can subtract the lifetime budget?
3. What can I do in Python so that the script runs each day and runs for the whole day and then closes at the end of the day.

Answer (score 1):

The sdk is using its own dict values as objects.  Use python's built in functions, covert to str.  Also, you really don't need to use the Json dump, you can just convert the str to csv and then to pandas df.

```
 me = objects.AdUser(fbid='me')
    my_accounts = (me.get_ad_accounts())
`   my_account = my_accounts[0]
    a = str(my_account)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialize custom made objects. Instead you could create a python dictionary with the values you need and then serialize that:

```
  for adset in adsets:
    print(adset[AdSet.Field.name])
    adset_json = {'name': adset[AdSet.Field.name], 
                  'budget': adset[AdSet.Field.lifetime_budget]}
    json.dump(adset_json, f)
```

Storing and reading with JSON is trivial: json.dump() and json.load()

For running the script daily I would recommend using a linux machine (or virtual machine) and setting up a Cron job (Cron is used to schedule tasks in linux). I am sure there is an equivalent method to do this in windows but I would not know how.